# How to get the values of TListView selected item in Firemonkey Delphi Rio

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firedac, livebindings, tlistview

I have a TListView populated with data from TFDQuery using Livebindings.

I would like to get the values of the selected item like the item.text, itemheader.text, etc. I already figured out the selected item through listview1.itemindex but to get the values is a struggle to me. I am new with TListView and livebindings. I've spent over a day already looking for answers in the internet but looks too complicated for a very simple task. I know there is a straight method for this.

Anyone care to share some clues (codes) on how to get the values of listview selected item?

### MORE DETAILS:

I am using the Livebindings dynamic appearance. I created items for my query fields and map them accordingly to my TListView.

It so happen that I did not use the default item.text but instead map fields to my created items like item.text1, item.text2, item.item3.

Hence, this is the reason why I am not getting the caption from the formula given by MartynA below.

Comment: @LURD I tried accessing the items using show message but no avail. I think it is an array. Can you give a brief code to at least generate the items?
var: sample : string;
sample := lsvSize.Items[lsvSize.ItemIndex].ToString;
ShowMessage(sample);

Comment: `sample := lsvSize.Items[lsvSize.ItemIndex].Caption;` will give you the `Caption` property. Another property is `SubItems`. See [Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem_Properties)

Comment: You left out the most important detail: Are you asking about a VCL  TListView or an FireMonkey one?

Comment: @MartynA Nice that you asked! I am asking about the firemonkey one. My bad! sorry for not so clear about this.

Comment: This is the reason why I can't push @LURD 's suggestion as he is pointing vcl properties.

Comment: I am surprised there are not much documentation about listview selected item. All I can find are embarcadero's basic infos which are hard to figure out in action. I will update my question here to give you the full details of what I am trying to do with listview.selected item.

Comment: The details you've added don't really help, I'm afraid - we need to see the code you are using to create and populate the listviews.

Comment: Yeah! I know. I realized that. However, I already figured out while doing the MRE. It was in the livebinding. Your answer below actually works and it helps. I mistakenly map the caption to my created item that should suppose to be the item.text. I will mark your answer below as final and will provide more details on it. Many many thanks @MartynA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing your point (in which case I'll delete this) but the following FMXcode works fine for me:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index : Integer;
begin
  Index := ListView1.ItemIndex;
  if Index >= 0 then
    Caption := ListView1.Items[Index].Text;
//  OR  ShowMessage(ListView1.Items[Index].Text);
//  OR  Label1.Text := ListView1.Items[Index].Text;

end;
```

Comment: I tried your procedure with ShowMessage. I am getting the right ItemIndex but the Caption doesn't show anything. It's empty.

Comment: Sorry, without seeing your .FMX file, I've no idea why that might be but the alternatives I've added to my answer both **do** work as well, so hasn't that answered your q?

Comment: I'll come up with MRE. Give me a minute.

Comment: I will no longer give you the MRE as I found already where I was missing. I mistakenly map the caption to my created item in livebindings instead of the default item.text. Now, I am getting the caption correctly. Your answer actually helps. I will improve my question and remove irrelevant details.